# how to set index.html to another page, not homepage

Tags: html, node.js, indexing

I want to show index.html on special page '/chess', not on home page '/'.

Simple

```
app.get('/chess', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');

});
```

doesn't work.

I get the below error

[image]

Comment: What do you want to happen when someone visits the root URL `/`? Should they see a page at that `/` URL, or should they be redirected to the URL `/chess`?

Comment: They should see select.html page

Comment: is something else using port 3000 when you try to start your app on port 3000?

Comment: Only me. When I go on index page, it report about new connection

Comment: "Address in use" is someting that indicates another process is using that port. It could be another instance of the same app, or you could have another app using the same port. Switch the port number if you have conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create more of the "game center" try the approach of making realchess a router that gets imported to the main app.js

below is how I was able to achieve the desired result

rename app.js to chess.js
chess.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('dashboard'));
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

... rest of code ...

http.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('listening on *: ' + port);
});
```

becomes

```
module.exports = function(server){
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express.Router();
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(express.static('dashboard'));
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    ... rest of code ...

    return app;
}
```

remove lines 145-147 and add `module.exports = app;`

create a new app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const chess = require("./chess")(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app
    .get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/selector.html");
    })
    .use("/", express.static("public"))
    .use("/chess",chess);

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on *: ' + port);
});
```

this will mound the chess router on the /chess directory, and allow you to mount a selector.html at /.  Following a similar patter you could mount other games

Comment: You saved my life. Thanks, maybe I give you back something(after some time). How do you find this info?

Comment: Strange thing - when I login - it doesn't show user, and I can't play game

Comment: 2 users doesn't work. I can login, but can't find another user(( I open two localhost :3000/chess pages, and login on both. After login, I see only my created login name, but not another user .

Comment: No registered user and connections

Comment: Try these new updates, I forgot about the socket part, and was just mounting the express app, instead of the http server that uses express and socket.io.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below i was able to remap

route '/chess' to serve index.html,

And

route '/' to serve select.html.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app
    .get("/", (req, res)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/select.html");
    })
    .get("/chess", (req, res)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
    });

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!"));
```

Can you post more of you application to see if there is another problem?

Comment: I download this https://github.com/dwcares/realchess and I want to see first select page, then choose between 4 - 6 games. User choose chess, and go to index.html page. I get error because this app.listen...   stuff

Comment: My misunderstanding.  So you are wanting to build a game hub, and this would be one of the games they could select?

/ => "Choose your game: Chess, Checkers, Tic-Tac-Toe, Chinese Checkers"
/chess => "real chess app"
...

Comment: Is changing the source for realchess an option for your game center?

Comment: Yes, but chess part should work. 2 players, one board and socket connection

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to declare the public director using use method.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```